# Why some links load in different Facebook browsers on iOS? (Blue vs black header)

Tags: facebook, browsers, ios

So, I've noticed while browsing facebook that some most links that I click on open in the usual Facebook browser, with the blue header, address bar, and footer. But then every once in a while I come across a link that loads (quite quickly) with a thin black header, and no footer or address bar. These pages seem pretty minimal, only showing the relevant content.

Here are two examples I found, both from Slate, one of each kind. I've viewed the source of both and cannot find out what in the code (if anything) causes Facebook to load it differently.

- Blue Header http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2016/01/22/blizzard_of_2016_live_blog_winter_snow_storm_updates.html
  [image: Blue Header with address bar, loads slower]
- Black Header http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/roads/2016/01/inside_the_workshop_that_produces_ghana_s_fanstastical_pop_art_coffins.html
  [image: Black Header, no address bar, super fast load]

Can anyone explain why this happens, and is there anything I can code into my webpages to cause them to load with the thin black header? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AHHH! Finally found it, with much Googling. This feature is called "Instant Articles"

https://instantarticles.fb.com/

That site contains a description of this feature and a video about it. Hope this helps someone else!